# Working with two git commits

Tags: git, gerrit, git-gui, changelist

I am working on project with git as version control.

I made first commit, pushed it to gerrit for review.

I started further development and made second commit, pushed it also to gerrit for review.

Now, I got some merge conflict in first commit and some feedback on second commit. I have to incorporate these changes:

I followed following steps:

1. `git reset --soft Head~1`  --> This got the HEAD to previous change
2. Resolved conflicts
3. Uploaded the new patchset for Commit1 (I used `git gui` - Amend Last Commit option for this)
4. Incorporated Feedback on Commit2
5. Added all file from Commit2 and made fresh commit. There was not option to amend the Commit2 from `git gui` now.

What should be Ideally done in this case so that I can amend previous Commit2 instead of creating new commit.

PS: The situation becomes even more tricky, if there are some other changes merged between these changes. This gets those changes when `Amend Last Commit` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Working with gerrit can be problematic when you have a list of chained reviews. In this situation I tend to do the following:

- Create a new (local) branch from the parent of the first commit.
- Cherry pick the first commit from Gerrit onto my local branch, and correct it using `git commit --amend`
- Now cherry pick the second commit on top of my amended version of the first commit
- resolve any conflicts that creates
- resolve the feedback from the review using `git commit --amend`
- Then pushup both commits with `git push origin <local branch>:refs/for/<remote branch>`

You can get the cherry-pick URL's straight from the Gerrit GUI for the change, and this preserves the change-id in the commit message so you just get a new patchset for each review, and they remain chained.

Git GUI apps are a useful way to explore a repository and its history. But they never really expose the full power of the git command line.